# AIC and n - original sample size or data points?

Tags: sample-size, aic

I've got a dataset consisting of 5,000 women, who are followed for 28 days, and for each day they have an estimated survival rate. I have taken these 28 survival rates, tried different models, and are therefore using AIC to evaluate these models.

However, I'm now in doubt when calculating AIC: is *n* = the 5,000 women, or the 28 survival rates?

Comment: What do you mean by "tried different models" What are the actual models that you are using AIC for ? Please provide more detail.

Comment: I tried fitting Exponential, logistic, gamma, beta and lognormal models to the data points